# Magento Controller Not found error

Tags: magento-1.9

I am facing the issue in my magento store i have create module its working fine on local ,dev enivorment but on live some time its not work and give error not found what will be the issue

Answer (score 2):

Try add this code into **index.php** line 76

```
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);    
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Or you can try using A Better Magento 404 Better to debug
http://alanstorm.com/magento-404-debug/

Hope it helpful for you